# Retrieve all commit messages between two pipeline executions in Gitlab CICD

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have a Gitlab CICD pipeline that builds and deploys a Java application.

When the pipeline runs I need to get all the new Git commit messages between the last execution of the pipeline and the current one.

E.g:

The previous pipeline execution last commit was:

```
commit 0f22ff72089axxx
   My old commit
```

Since then there have been two more commits:

```
commit 234ff72089axxx
   My new commit 1

commit 5454422089axxx
   My new commit 2
```

When the pipeline executes again I need to get

```
My new commit 1
My new commit 2
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines) to fetch the list of pipelines ran for your branch:

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines?ref=:branch&scope=finished
```

- `:id` is your project ID found in **Settings > General**.
- `:branch` is your branch name which can be retrieved from the predefined `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` variable in CI.
- `scope=finished` just excludes pending or running pipelines.

This will return a list of objects that looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 4717,
        "iid": 1563,
        "project_id": 87,
        "sha": "6d019ba714992aca9ee07c24664f04e4d05aac44",
        "ref": "my-branch",
        "status": "success",
        "source": "push",
        "created_at": "2022-09-05T23:24:40.613-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-05T23:26:31.249-07:00",
        "web_url": "REDACTED"
    },
    ...
]
```

This is sorted by pipeline ID by default, so the first item should be the most recent completed pipeline. You'll need to get the `sha` from that item for use in the next step.

Then you can use `git log` to get the commit messages for a range of commits:

```bash
git log --pretty=format:%s --no-merges <previous-sha>..<current-sha>
```

- `--pretty=format:%s` causes `git log` to only show the first line of commit messages.
- `--no-merges` excludes merge commits, which seems reasonable to me but you can remove it.
- `<previous-sha>` is the `sha` we retrieved from the API response.
- `<current-sha>` is the value of the predefined `CI_COMMIT_SHA` variable in CI.

This will output something similar to this, with the commits ordered newest to oldest:

```bash
$ git log --pretty=format:%s --no-merges <previous-sha>..<current-sha>
Commit message of commit currently being built
The previous commit message
...
```

You can add the `--reverse` flag to `git log` to reverse the ordering of the commits for oldest to newest.

Comment: This does not take into account when pipelines are re-run, especially out of order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitLab's API to get info on a [specific pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline)

Check whether you should take `sha` or `before_sha` when you are inspecting the pipelines state while it is running.